# Setting CmdExecTimeout in Firedac database connection leads to bad performance

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac

Setting FDConnection.ResourceOptions.CmdExecTimeout to anything other than $FFFFFFFF seemingly forces  firedac to create and destroy a thread for every call to the database. When debugging in XE5 this slows the app down to a crawl. 
Is there another setting to pool threads? Maybe FDManager can help?

Comment: There is no thread pool for commands with a timeout specified. You should set CmdExecTimeout only for the commands, which really require this.

Comment: I'm guessing you do not use the inbuilt timeouts in the underlying SQL Server drivers? This is how ADO was working. Is there a way we can set  the timeout at a driver level?

Comment: No, we do not. This feature request will be considered for next RAD Studio versions. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: This was fixed in XE7 but seems to have regressed in XE7 update 1. Anybody encountered this?